# how many types of orphan package are there

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman, aur

I clean orphan packages sometimes on Arch or Ubuntu based OS.

But some of them not at `pacman` or `yay` list

```
paru -Ss dfu-util
community/dfu-util 0.10-1 [34.94KB 104.31KB]
    Tool intended to download and upload firmware using DFU protocol to devices
    connected over USB
aur/qm-dfu-util 1.2.0-1 [+1 ~0.00] [Orphaned]
    UART-based dfu-util for Quark MCUs
aur/dfu-util-git 20200630-2 [+1 ~0.40]
    Tool intended to download and upload firmware using DFU protocol to devices
    connected over USB
aur/qm-dfu-util-git r373.9aa7b29-1 [+0 ~0.00] [Orphaned]
    UART-based dfu-util for Quark MCUs
```

such as above orphaned `qm-dfu-util` package not in list of `pacman` which same list `paru` or `yay`

```
pacman -Qdt  
appstream 0.14.0-4
chrpath 0.16-3
dejagnu 1.6.2-2
doxygen 1.9.1-1
gcc9-fortran 9.3.0-5
gendesk 1.0.6-1
ghostpcl 9.53.3-2
ghostxps 9.53.3-2
gobject-introspection 1.66.1-3
gtk2-perl 1.24993-2
guile2.0 2.0.14-4
jbigkit 2.1-5
js52 52.9.0-4
js68 68.12.0-1
ld-lsb 3-7
lib32-alsa-oss 1.1.8-2
lib32-gst-plugins-base-libs 1.18.3-1
lib32-libxslt 1.1.34-1
lib32-lz4 1.9.3-1
lib32-ocl-icd 2.2.14-1
lib32-v4l-utils 1.20.0-1
lib32-vkd3d 1.2-2
libmagick6 6.9.11.60-1
libstdc++5 3.3.6-7
libuvc 0.0.6-1
linux-latest 5.10-1
linux-latest-virtualbox-host-modules 5.10-1
meson 0.56.2-1
mhwd-nvidia-340xx 340.108-1
opencl-headers 2:2020.12.18-1
opera-ffmpeg-codecs 88.0.4324.104-1
patchelf 0.12-1
python-sip4 4.19.24-1
python2-gobject 3.36.1-3
qt4 4.8.7-33
rust 1:1.49.0-1
vkd3d 1.2-1
wxgtk2 3.0.5.1-2
x11vnc 1:0.9.16-4
xorg-server-xvfb 1.20.10-3
```

Why some packages not included in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orphaned can mean two things:

1. An AUR package is unmaintained
2. A package was installed as a dependency but is no longer required by any package

`pacman -Qdt` lists all packages meeting the second criteria but I do not recommend removing all of them. Some like `meson` are makedepends needed to build an AUR package. You can run `pacman -D --asexplicit meson` as root to clean `meson` from the `pacman -Qdt` list.

Of course, it is not dangerous to remove `meson` but if an AUR package using it receives an update, you would need to reinstall `meson`.

Comment: Can I track unmaintained packages?

Comment: This [PR](https://github.com/Morganamilo/paru/pull/240) adds the option `-P --stats` to display orphaned packages among other things. You can also create an account on the AUR website and click “Enable notifications” on individual packages. You can change your notification settings if you click on “My Account”.